# Reload parent page from PHP page loaded in DIV tag

Tags: php, parent-child, parent, reload

Hi I have a PHP page loading in a DIV tag from a javascript function. I also have a button on this PHP page that sends information to another PHP page. I was using header to go back to the page I was on (still in the div tag) but I was wondering if there is a way to reload the original parent page. The pages are all saved in separate files so I was unsure how to do this. I have tried using Javascript such as top, window, and opener for location.reload() e.g.
`top.location.reload()
window.location.reload()`
and saving the function on each page as
`function myFunctio(){
location.reload();
}` and then calling it on each page again using top, window, and opener but nothing has worked. If I use a header it will only load the page in the DIV.

Comment: Have you tried `window.opener.location.reload(false);` ?

Comment: I have now and it doesn't seem to work. I did not realise they could be used in sequence like that so I have fiddled around and found that top.window.location.reload(); works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Excellent, would you mind if I stuck that in an answer for a green tick?

Comment: Of course not, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use them in sequence to get the result you're looking for give something like `window.opener.location.reload(false);` a try